# Extracting results from a job when it is in a json form

Tags: qiskit, ibm-quantum-devices, ibm-q-experience

I have downloaded a job from the [COMPOSER JOBS](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/jobs) but I get a folder containing three files.

1. 632867a95ccea778be9446fb-info.json
2. 632867a95ccea778be9446fb-input.json
3. 632867a95ccea778be9446fb-output.json

Is there any python code to load my job (from one of these files) and extract my result from it?

Answer (score 1):

[`Result`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.result.Result.html) class supports loading experiment result data from a dictionary. So, all what you need is to load the output file as any json file then pass its contents to [`Result.from_dict()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.result.Result.from_dict.html) method:

```
import json
from qiskit.result import Result

f = open('path/to/output-file.json')
data = json.load(f)

result = Result.from_dict(data)
print(result.get_counts())
```